# Sourcing ~/.bashrc in ~/.profile?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, bashrc, .profile

I'm quite new to developing under OSX and assigned some aliases and other preferences in the ~/.profile initially, however it got quite big and messy after a while because I had a lot of Environment Variables to define too.

So I created a ~/.bashrc file (as you would on linux) and placed all my aliases and preferences there. However, since every instance of mac terminal is a login terminal, it doesn't read the .bashrc but just .profile...

So my solution was to place a `source .bashrc` at the bottom of ~/.profile and that does the job. So I'm wondering whether that is not good and if there is a better and cleaner way of doing that, since this is a bit of a hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953005/should-the-bashrc-in-the-home-directory-load-automatically/9954208#9954208

See here. 
It's OK to add `source ~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile`.

Comment: Oh, that is a very helpful diagram. So if I understood correctly it is actually better to source it from .bash_login? However (since it is FIRST) would it reach my .profile, to instantiate my env vars?

Comment: @G.Rassovsky Actually I haven't used .bash_login myself. .profile won't get reached if there exists .bash_login. Maybe it's better to use ~/.profile (in my opinion).

Comment: ah yes, i think you're actually right, i didn't spot this straight away... so best just keep my source .bashrc in .profile and not worry too much about it. :)